# Update file, but not alter file modify date. Can it be done?

Tags: linux

In Linux, can i change file content, but keep the same modification date of that file? If yes, then how? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get what is the modification Date of your file.
Change your files content and then you can change the modification date by `touch` command.For example

```
touch -m -t 09082000 file
to change the modification time to 8 sep, 20:00.
```

You can change the modification date to the past too, for 10/15/1998 12:30 the command would be something like this:

```
touch -m -t 19981015123000 file
```

Comment: I want to execute search and replace script on large number of file, how would I go about implementing this in the script. For example I want to run this [ find . -iname "*.txt" | xargs sed -i '/s/str1/str2/' ]. How do I add get modify time-stamp, alter content, then change modify time-stamp to its original value?

Comment: http://www.dent.med.uni-muenchen.de/~kkunzelm/exponent-0.96.3/index.php?section=85 take a look this could help you.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

another possibility might be a symbolic link?

if you have `alink->a.txt`, you change the content of a.txt, the last modi time of alink won't be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can memorize the modification date before modifying the content; After the content modification, you can modify back the date to the initial value. It can be done in Linux from the command line. For example:

touch -t 09082000 file
to change the modification time to 8 sep, 20:00. More info [can be found here.](http://www.lampdocs.com/blog/2008/10/how-to-change-last-modified-date-of-the-file-to-a-time-in-the-past-in-linux/)

Answer (score 2):

As I had a similar problem now and found this question via google, I'll give an easy, automatic solution. I store the current modification time in the variable `CURRENT`, then after modifying the file, I set the modification time back to its original time via `touch`. Please note that getting the timestamp for current is a bit clumsy, you might need to modify it a bit.

```
FILE=test.txt
touch $FILE
CURRENT=$(date -r $FILE +%Y%m%d%H%M)
# run your command here
touch $FILE 
touch -a -m -t $CURRENT $FILE
```