# Bash: Check if file was modified since used in script

Tags: file, bash, shell, compare

I need to check in a script if a file was modified since I read it (another application can modify it in between). According to bash manual there is a "-N" test which should report if a file was modified since last read. I tried it in a small script but it seems like it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="test.txt"
echo "test" > $file
cat $file;
if [ -N $file ];
    then echo "modified since read";
else
    echo "not modified since read";
fi
```

I also tried an alternative way by touching another file and using

```
if [ "file1" -nt "file2 ];
```

but this works only on a seconds accuracy which may under rare conditions not be sufficient. Is there any other bash-inbuilt solution for this problem or I do really need to use diff or md5sum?

Comment: If second-resolution accuracy is important, I'm not sure sharing a file this way is the best idea, sockets may be better, since you currently have no way of telling whether the other program is done with it. But can you modify the other program?  If so, some sort of lock mechanism would make sense, both allowing you to (a) know when it's modified, and (b) know when the other application is finished for the moment.

Comment: @Tomas Absent ACL lists, unix does not have file locking at the kernel level. If another process has permissions to write your file then there is no way to know if there is a write pending.

Comment: What is the bigger concern? Up until your actual write the other application has the correct copy of the file. After your write the file pages will be marked as dirty and subsequent reads will get the updated pages. If you do not intend for other processes to have the old version then change the file permissions.

Comment: @starbolin: jedwards wasn't talking about file locking, but a *lock file* (a cooperative mechanism).

Comment: Thomas, is `atime` turned on for your filesystem (`mount` doesn't show "noatime")?

Comment: @starbolin, jedwards: I have an application which writes out a lot of log files (I don't have source of this application so I can't change it). The script shall parse these files and if some things are found write out a mail. However, I need to be absolutely sure that I don't miss a change (it is possible that there is no other update for a longer time in one file so if I miss a change in the sub-second part it's bad).

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, atime should be set to on:

    /dev/vzfs on / type reiserfs (rw,usrquota,grpquota)

Comment: @Tomas Normally one would either of: copy the log file and parse the copy while the app fills up a new file, or, stream the logs through a filter and tee out the data you are interested in.  Locking the log file on an unknown app would be dangerous. Either way you don't loose any data.  Possible delay in all cases is at least the time it takes to read a line and to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing file hashes (md5/sha1) is probably the only robust way to know (and audit) file changes, lest someone [attempt to circumvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095415/update-file-but-not-alter-file-modify-date-can-it-be-done) your attempts to detect file modifications. Also, rather than (or in addition to) periodically polling, you could implement some kind of file change notification: see [this s.u. question](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes) for suggestions (e.g., using [inotifywait](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/)).

But if it seems your scripts are gradually converging on a revision control system, just put these files in a git repo and let git detect and manage the changes for you.

(Edit:  I just noticed that these are scripts monitoring log files (I was thinking you were monitoring actual scripts for file changes), in which case putting them under version control really wouldn't be appropriate.)